# Switching hard drive in Lenovo Flex 2 14

Tags: thinkpad, laptop-repair

I have a Lenovo Flex 2 14 with mechanical hard drive. I bought an SSD to switch it but I encountered a problem opening the laptop.

I followed the manual here: [manual](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_flex_2_14_flex_2_14d_flex_2_15_flex_2_15d_hmm.pdf)


I started by removing the keyboard, all went well.

then came the part where it said to remove the optical drive, having no optical drive (14 inch don’t have it) I just skipped this part, the next part was taking off the back panel, I took all the screw off and then started peeling the panel off starting at the front. The back side of the panel didn’t seem to go out.

Instead of using more pressure I stopped because i realized maybe the 14 inch version has something similar to the optical drive removal that needs to be done before the back panel removal.

 
the manual just list the optical drive removal as a step, without any clarification about the 14 inch version.

Anyone has experience with opening up the 14 version and can help?

Comment: Consider adding a picture of your current situation. That might encourage users to respond to your question.

Comment: Even though there's no actual optical drive installed, did you confirm that the screw mentioned in that step isn't there?

Comment: agteover - I already put it back together (it's the computer I use).
Techie007 - There is no screw there (where the step point out) I did unscrews any that are on the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.

I found this [post](http://wolfbrother.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/lenovo-flex-2-14-teardown.html) about opening the lenovo flex 2 14. To sum it up:

after you remove the keyboard, there are 3 screws you need to take out (under the keyboard), 1 of them is hidden under a sticker (I guess it's a warranty sticker).

After you do this, you take off the 9~ screws on the back panel and then you can remove it :)

I will add that in order to switch the HDD you also need to take out the battery, pulling off the connector is a little tricky, there's not much to hold on to so be careful.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the ODD screw under a small sticker. I imagine the screw is present even w/o an ODD, and is very likely under a sticker.

Comment: This information is already contained in the other answer, so your answer adds nothing.